# HTML Table with thousands of rows

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom

I have a server that will supply a list of objects in json, and I would like to display them in a table on the client side.

My initial instinct was to edit the DOM after I got the results from the server. Create the entire table DOM element from the json, and then call replaceChild on the element that contains the table.

However, there are thousands of rows, and perhaps due to its size, the ui freezes as the table is being updated. Furthermore, this process seems a bit hacky -- manipulating the DOM directly seems like it should be done in a library. I'm also thinking of implementing pagination to address the flickering issue, but again, it feels like I'm solving a general problem to address my specific one.

What would be the right thing to do here? The task seems like it would be common enough. Are there better ways to go about this than just hacking the DOM, or is that just what you're supposed to do?

Comment: For that many rows to display, you might instead consider pagination.

Comment: There are libraries for this. One example would be jquery datatables: http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: jQuery has some plugins that do pagination nicely. Which is probably what you need. Though depending on how many records it may not be the best experience to unload them all on the client, but rather go with a server side processing approach for the pagination

Comment: Have you tried accumulating the formatted HTML into a huge string and then using `.innerHTML` to place it on the page? It seems like that might be faster than doing `createElement` and `appendChild` in a loop.

Comment: Maybe you could do 100 at a time, loading the next 100 when the user scrolls the 90th onto the page. I believe a search for "infinite scroll" should yield some results.

Comment: What is the page supposed to be used for? Who is going to read thousands of rows? You should probably consider how to create tools for users to generate tables they have some use for, containing *relevant* information.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I was actually hoping to add a search bar afterwards, but I also wanted to allow the user to browse through the listings if they wanted.

Comment: @prawn I would have preferred to have that done serverside as well, but due to historical baggage, it doesn't look like the server is going to support a better api for the time being.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid).

It has a very fast rendering speed by applying something they call adaptive virtual scrolling (very much like what @Grim commented I think).

Here's a chunk of code based on [one](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/gh-pages/examples/example1-simple.html) of their basic examples:

**HTML:**

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="50%">
      <div id="myGrid" style="width:600px;height:500px;"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
  var grid;
  var columns = [
    {id: "title",    name: "Title",    field: "title"},
    {id: "duration", name: "Duration", field: "duration"},
    {id: "start",    name: "Start",    field: "start"},
    {id: "finish",   name: "Finish",   field: "finish"}
  ];

  var options = {
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    enableColumnReorder: false
  };

  $(function () {
    var data = getYourJSONDataArray();
    grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
  });
```

The keys on your JSON objects have to match the field values on the columns array.